# Como sumar 2 arreglos en un nuevo java

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esto de programar y tengo la duda de como sumar estos 2 arreglos para que me de un 3ro, osea que arreglo1 (5,8,9,2,3) sumado con arreglo2 (7,9,2,6,4) de un 3ro con la suma de ambos, ya que solamente se sumarlos de manera simple

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arreglo1 []  ={5,8,9,2,3};
    int arreglo2 [] = {7,9,2,6,4};

    int subtotal = 0;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int total =0;

    for (int x=0;x<arreglo1.length;x++){

        num1 =arreglo1[x];
        num2 =arreglo2[x];
        subtotal= num1+num2;
        total = subtotal;

        System.out.println(total);

            }

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Casi lo tienes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arreglo1 = {5,8,9,2,3};
    int[] arreglo2 = {7,9,2,6};

    if(arreglo1.length != arreglo2.length)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error: Los arreglos son de diferente tamaño.");

    int sumas [] = new int[arreglo1.length];

    int total = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < sumas.length; x++){
        sumas[x] = arreglo1[x] + arreglo2[x];
        total += sumas[x];
        System.out.print("[" + sumas[x] + "]");
    }

    System.out.println("\nTOTAL: " + total);
}
```

Nada más ten cuidado cuando `arreglo1` y `arreglo2` son de diferente tamaño porque el programa caería.

Comment: gracias con esto ya me aclare para añadir mas detalles al codigo, muuchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crearte un array auxiliar (el tercero) y recorrer como lo estabas haciendo pero guardando la suma en él, y **NO** en la variable **total**. Es importante que lo inicialices con **new** como he hecho. Si hay algo que no entiendas no dudes en dejar un comentario.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    int arreglo1 []  ={5,8,9,2,3};
    int arreglo2 [] = {7,9,2,6,4};
    int suma[] = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ ){
        suma[i] = arreglo1[i] + arreglo2[i];
    }

    System.out.println(suma);
}
```

Comment: muuchimas gracias me sirvió bastante, con esto ya pude hacer otras cosas, gracias